# OSX El Capitan - Spaces bar - Show expanded window thumbnails/previews by default?

Tags: osx-spaces, osx-el-capitan, expose, mission-control

One of the new features of Mac OSX "El Capitan" (10.11) is that ["the Spaces Bar has been shrunk, only displaying Desktop and window names by default—revealing your full desktop windows on mouseover."](http://www.imore.com/whats-changed-os-x-el-capitan)

[image]

Is there any way to revert back to showing the expanded (on mouseover) thumbnails/previews/tiles instead of window names by default in the Mission Control "Spaces Bar"?

[image]

It now takes two gestures instead of one to get a bird's eye view of all your spaces due to the new default collapsed behavior.  While this may be preferred by some, and might be beneficial on smaller screens, it's killing productivity on my setup with multiple large monitors.

At minimum this **OBVIOUSLY** should be user configurable but I haven't yet been able to locate any preferences using `defaults read` for various namespaces (`NSGlobalDomain`, `com.apple.dock`, `com.apple.dashboard`, `com.apple.spaces`).

What a *terrible* "enhancement"....  >_<

Comment: totally agree, I didnt realise this feature until this morning when I sat down and finished the install, although I love how scrollbars are back by default....

Comment: Keep in mind this is actually a huge benefit for small screens... But even in my 13'' mbp, I personally *think* I do prefer the thumbnails. (haven't tried captain yet!)

Comment: @Cawas That's the proposed benefit but I definitely prefer the thumbnails even when using just my MBP laptop (and no additional external monitors).  It also becomes vitally important when you have multiple windows of the same application (e.g. multiple iTerms, multiple SublimeTexts, multiple Chromes, etc.).

Comment: Android and iOS folders behave in a very similar way... They're visual, and I wouldn't trade that for textual representations. No way in hell. So I definitely agree with that feeling.

Comment: Great point, @Cawas. I definitely agree!

Answer (score 7):

Please go to http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html
And submit feedback, telling them you want (like many of us) this functionnality back.

Comment: I wonder if they truly ever listen, though...

Comment: I submitted feedback too.

Answer (score 3):

An available workaround is using the latest version of **BetterTouchTool** (BTT).

You can assign the new "**Mission control & Immediately show desktop previews**" action to a gesture (3-finger swipe up).

This does what expected, opens Mission Control and then expands the Spaces Bar. However the second animation happens only ofter the first one has finished, so the windows move about a bit.

Comment: Nice [but hopefully temporary] workaround. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be somehow worked around if you create at least 12 spaces, including fullscreen spaces. I do not know if this depends on your screen resolution, but it works ! I am using OSX 10.11.3